# openpyxl разложить в колонку измененые значения

Tags: python, openpyxl

Всем привет, подскажите новичку как решить данную задачу
book.xlsx на основе которой парсится book2.xlsx что то типа такого

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.open(filename="Path to file book.xlsx", read_only=True)

sheet = book.active
book1 = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheetbook1 = book1.active
row = 2
for i in range (1,11):
    sheetbook1[i][0].value = sheet[i][1].value
    sheetbook1[i][1].value = sheet[i][2].value
    sheetbook1[i][2].value = sheet[i][3].value
    sheetbook1[i][3].value = sheet[i][4].value
    sheetbook1[i][4].value = sheet[i][5].value
    sheetbook1[i][5].value = sheet[i][12].value
    sheetbook1[i][6].value = sheet[i][11].value
    row = row+1
book1.save("book2.xlsx")
book1.close()
```

Тут все в порядке, на выходе получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как на основе вычитанных данных распарсить еще одну таблицу, но с изменненными значениями?

```
sheetbook1[i][4].value = sheet[i][5].value
```

Например к этому значению добавить или отнять 10% и на основе новых данных сохранить book3.xlsx?

Comment: `sheetbook1[i][4].value = sheet[i][5].value + sheet[i][5].value/10` ?